# Cordova compile android error

Tags: android, cordova, ant, compiler-errors, apk

I wanted to compile my project to a .apk to run on my android phone. I get an error when I try this. It says that the system variable `JAVA_HOME` doesn't refer to the right place (pictures below).

The error says it refers to the jre from Java, but if you take a look the one of the images below, you see it refers to the JDK. I also posted a picture of which Java things I have in my Java map.

I don't know if the error shows up, because of the systemvariables. Perhaps something else is causing this error. If you can find it or you need more information about this error, please let me know.

**The error in the cmd when compiling the project**
[image: The error in the cmd]

**Those are the systemvariables**
[image: The systemvariables]

**Those are the uservariables**
[image: The usersvariables]

**Java map**
[image: Java map]

Comment: You must close and restart the console if you have changed variables (JAVA_HOME). Did you do that?

Comment: Yes I did, @sergioFC

Comment: did you try to set a \ behind the folder in the PATH? Maybe cordova-forum.de is interesting for you. We had the problem with another user over there.

Comment: I just saw another issue... the directory the cmd is looking for is the JRE not the JDK. Seems you like you did not restart your console/computer.

Comment: I've tried to restart my computer several times, and it didn't work.. I'm working on this project for roughly 4 weeks and now I wanted to compile it, but it didn't work as you can see, @Sithys

Comment: Yeah i believe you but it is like i said already... the cmd is looking into the wrong path :-/ 

Could you do a fullquote of your path into a comment here or edit it inside your first post?

Comment: Full quote of what @Sithys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75115/discussion-between-m-zeinstra-and-sithys).